# How to find out all possible Exceptions that could be thrown (Specifically Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

This really is a generic C# question i think, but i thought about it when trying to handle Entity Framework when persisting the data using *ObjectContext* and specifically **SaveChanges()**

Now usually i would just follow what the MSDN documentation advises and the appropriate try/catch logic for the required Exceptions. Example is the following for SaveChanges():

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx

Now im posing this question because reading the above link, there is one Exception listed, called **OptimisticConcurrencyException** which is fine. Now reading the example they give there is another listed **UpdateException**. Now I would expect that to be listed within the Exceptions heading.

So going back to the original question, "How to i know all of the exceptions that could be thrown from an Object or their methods"?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You can look through the source code of that method and every method it calls (that's not in a catch-all block).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe you can.  However if you look at the inheritance structure of [OptimisticConcurrencyException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.optimisticconcurrencyexception.aspx) it inherits from:

```
System.Object
  System.Exception
    System.SystemException
      System.Data.DataException
        System.Data.UpdateException
          System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException
```

If you catch `System.Data.DataException` it should catch both without having to do a catch-all.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is only one exception as you point out **OptimisticConcurrencyException**. If you see the code carefully, then you can notice *SaveChanges()* only throw this exception only.

**UpdateException** is not for *SaveChanges()* but for

```
ObjectQuery<SalesOrderHeader> orders =
            context.SalesOrderHeaders.Where(
            "it.CreditCardApprovalCode IS NULL").Top("100");
```

or Other line of code in that example.

Comment: You are right, thanks matey for looking, tired eyes :(